# TypeScript VS 2013.3 not generating AMD

Tags: typescript, amd

I am trying to get type script to generate AMD files. I've tried in VS, by checking AMD, and tried using tsc.exe by hand. I'm adding --module AMD. I've tried a lot of things. The output files have no define at the beginning. They always start by assigning to a var.

What could I possibly be missing?

Answer (score 1):

> The output files have no define at the beginning. They always start by assigning to a var.
>   What could I possibly be missing?

Perhaps you are not using the `export` keyword at the *top* scope of your file e.g.

```
export var foo = 123;
```

Comment: They're all inside of modules. I added 'export' to all my modules, and now they're just not referenceable.

Comment: Oh.... apparently you can't have multiple module exports across files.... goodness. This throws a wrench into things.